# Windows 10 PC has a desktop folder inside another

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, files-folders

For some reason this is my folder structure:
[image: Folder Structure]

I have a `Desktop` folder nested inside the `This PC` folder which is in another `Desktop` folder. I cannot figure out how to fix this.

As far as I know, this is how it is supposed to be:

[image: Correct folders]

What should I do???

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Before I vote to close this question, do you by chance have "show all files" as indicated by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYe23.png) image?

Comment: @Ramhound I do have show all folders checked... I don;t know where the files one is...

Comment: @Ramhound Ok! Thanks for the link... I unchecked the folders thing and now it is fine! Thanks!